# Making collections available on the client without meteor startup

Tags: javascript, meteor

When i define my meteor collections on the server and try to access them in the client without being in any of the meteor provided methods `rendered, events, created, helpers ...` I always get an error that says `Meteor collection not defined` if i try to redefine the method in the client, i get the `Meteor collection already exists`. I am able to get around this by referencing my custom made collections in a `Meteor.startup()` function. How can i reference the collection i defined on the server in the client. In the meteor docs there able to create two instances of `Meteor.Collection()` and subscribe even before declaring.

```
// okay to subscribe (and possibly receive data) before declaring
// the client collection that will hold it.  assume "allplayers"
// publishes data from **server's "players" collection.**
Meteor.subscribe("allplayers");
...
// client queues incoming players records until ...
...
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can place `Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");` at the top of your file without it being in `Meteor.startup`. Make sure its defined before you initiate `Meteor.subscribe`

e.g your file could be:

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");
MyCollection2 = new Meteor.Collection("MyCollection2");

Meteor.subscribe("allplayers");
Meteor.subscribe("mycollection2");

..rest of stuff
```

Something a bit cleaner might be to create a file in your project's root directory containing this so that its used on both the client and the server without you having to redefine them for each e.g a `collection.js` in your project root could contain

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");
MyCollection2 = new Meteor.Collection("MyCollection2");

if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("allplayers");
    Meteor.subscribe("mycollection2");   
}
```

so now you don't have to define `Players` or `MyCollection2` on your `/server` or `/client` anymore. The way meteor loads files will ensure that this is defined before your other regular files. This probably works best if you've arranged your files in the `/client`,`/server` and `/public` format as used on the other meteor examples (parties & todo)

Edit: as BenjaminRH suggests, putting your file in `/lib/collections.js` assures it will be loaded even before other files in your root project dir.

Comment: I usually put my collections in `/lib/collections.js`, the `/lib` folder assuring that it's loaded before `/client` or `/server`.

Comment: @BenjaminRH if we put all collection definitions inside of /lib, can i reference in any file under /client or /server ?

Comment: @Warz yes any collection defined in this file will be accessible by both the client & server. In the lib directory it is assured to be loaded before other files

Comment: @Warz please note, though, that with the new variable scoping, variables declared with `var` at the outer level of JavaScript files will be private to that file.

Comment: I have my Collections defined in /collections (both client and server) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use an ENV_VAR using process.env.VAR in the Collection definition (e.g. CFS:S3 setup which needs the AWS Secret Key).  How can this be set up to not call the ENV_VAR in the client?